# Replace word in string, regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, string

Use `String.Replace` to change word in line, for exapmle:

```
string s = "some_text or some-text or Text use text, read text or what text?";
            s = s.Replace("text", "1");
```

Result: `some_1 or some-1 or Text use 1, read 1 or what 1?`

but i need `some_text or some-text or 1 use 1, read 1 or what 1?`

How to fix this? Mayby regular expression or somethink else?

Update: for example string beginning on this word "Text some text ...."
Update2: "text-some"

Comment: could you explain which `text` you want to replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using string `split` and `replace`. Also had to use `ToLower()`

Here the result is exactly same as the OP's requirement. But had to use many if-else and condition checking. Actually this is the way logically we need to think if we need to achieve the result.

```
 string s = "some_text or some-text or Text use text, read text or what text?"; 
 string[] arr = s.Split(' '); // < separate by space

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // String builder instance

 foreach (string item in arr)
 {
        // Take to lower and check for text/Text but not _text , -Text 
        if (!item.ToLower().Contains("-text") && !item.ToLower().Contains("_text") && item.ToLower().Contains("text"))
        {
            // Simply replace Text or text 
            sb.Append(item.ToLower().Replace("text","1"));
        }
        else {
            // Else simply append 
            sb.Append(item);
        }
        sb.Append(' ');  // <= Adding space 
   }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); // <= Printing the output

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Output :

```
some_text or some-text or 1 use 1, read 1 or what 1?
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use word boundaries along with the ignorecase `i` modifier.

```
string replaced = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(?i)(?<=\s)text\b", "1");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xL6tD6/2)

`(?<=\s)` positive lookbehind assertion which asserts that the match must be preceded by a space character. `(?i)` case insensitive modifier. `\b` word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.

Comment: It what I need, but not working if string is beginning at this word: "Text and so one"

Comment: i don't what op wants.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this `String.Split` + `Enumerable.Select` + `String.Join` approach works for you:

```
char[] wordDelimiter = new[] { ' ','\t', ',', '.', '!', '?', ';', ':', '/', '\\', '[', ']', '(', ')', '<', '>', '@', '"', '\'' };
var newWords = s.Split(wordDelimiter)
    .Select(w => w.Equals("text", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? "1" : w);
string result = String.Join(" ", newWords);
```

Your desired result: `some_text or some-text or 1 use 1  read 1 or what 1`

Answer (score 0):

Variant of Avinash's Regex:

```
string replaced = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?i)(?<=^|[.,;:?! ])text(?=$|[.,;:?! ])", "1");
```

I don't use the `\b` because the `-` is a word boundary, so I check for `text` that follows the beginning of the text or one of `.,;:?!` and that is followed by end of the text or one of `.,;:?!`.

Comment: or simpler pattern: @"(?<!-)\btext\b(?!-)" . And if the OP wants to replace something like this : "--text--" then the patern would be: @"(?<!\w-)\btext\b(?!-\w)" . Plus, of course, IgnoreCase flag.

Comment: @Arie I always hated quite much (more than in general regexes) the `\b` anchor, because it is "illogical" and difficult to remember (word characters plus underscore vs non-word characters minus underscore... Why the underscore? How should a person remember it? Is it logical?)

Comment: I agree it's illogical (it's actually the hyphen character that baffles me, not underscore though). But sometimes it's usefull, especially when the alternative is specifying all possible characters that arent digits, spaces or letters.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
s= Regex.Replace( Regex.Replace( s, "^text", "1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), "\\stext", " 1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```